# Debugging Classic ASP with VS-2010; missing key-value pairs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, asp-classic

I'm debugging a Classic ASP website with VS 2010.

There is a problem with variable visualization. Key-value pairs are shown as strings, with the content being the key field.

**Example:**

I see this:

```
Name           |Value       |Type
---------------------------------
QueryString     {count=2}    IRequestDictionary
 [0]             "Name"       String
 [1]             "Age"        String
```

instead of something like this:

```
Name           |Value       |Type
---------------------------------
QueryString     {count=2}    IRequestDictionary
-[0]             "Name"       DictionaryItem
  key             "Name"       String
  value           "Jack"       String
-[1]             "Age"        DictionaryItem
  key             "Age"        String
  value           "25"         String
```

So basically I can't take a glance on values, though I could type the expression to evaluate it.

Is there anything I can do to make it happen? (configuration, addon..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: no.

Perhaps you are thinking of the way .NET dictionaries are displayed.  The debugger is simply displaying what it finds.  What you see when viewing a .NET dictionary is a result of how such a dictionary exposes its data.  Its a collection of KeyValuePairs.

However older COM/VB6/VBScript dictionaries don't work like that.  There is no type that describes an "item" in a dictionary.  Typically the enumeration of dictionary yields only the keys held by the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer Anthony! Actually I remember enumeration differences of old dictionaries, however I was hoping for a workaround (like a visualizer) or something. I don't remember this issue from VB6 days, maybe I was used to it. However I know some ASP debuggers which show key-value pairs for classic ASP VBS dictionaries.

Comment: I found this [ADCollectionsVisualizer](http://www.adamdawes.com/programming/vs2005/adcollectionsvisualizer.html) but I guess it can't directly run on a vbscript debug session... well then.. -)